# How to make stripos() look for exact match?

Tags: php, regex

I'm using stripos() to search for a given word. However, when I search for "fed", for example, it will return a match to "federal" as well, which I don't want. I want it to match "fed" only when it's a word on it's own.

I thought of using preg_match for this, however, I am using an array for my search and apparently I cannot use the caret symbol inside this type of pattern.

Code that worked without caret symbol:

```
if(preg_match("%$clean_title%",$clean_body))
```

Code that does not work:

```
if(preg_match("%^$clean_title%",$clean_body))
```

I don't think word boundaries would work here since I'm trying to match a word even if there is a comma after it (or a period).

Comment: What is `$clean_title`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
preg_match("%\byour-string\b%", $clean_body)
```

which matches if `your-string` is separated by spaces (before and after) and other non-word characters like space, tab, return, dash(-), etc. eg: '…hello your-string something…' will be a match but '…hello someotheryour-string something…' won't

<del>if you want a comma to be optional try the following:

     preg_match("%\byour-string,?\b%", $clean_body)</del>

Word boundaries consider `,`'s as non-word characters so it should work if you want ,'s or .'s after your word.

Comment: What if there's a comma after the word? And i want it to match this word too? I don't think boundaries would work here.